# Как переключить стрелками подсветку только верхнего элемента списка?

Tags: javascript, события, javascript-events

Нужно чтобы при переключении стрелками вверх-вниз менялся цвет фона элемента списка Local Disk(C:), (D:0), (E:). у меня есть отдельно функция ligth, которая меняет цвет подсветки нужного только родительского элемента. FirstChild для li не сработал. Не смогла придумать, как соединить эту функцию с нажатием стрелок. Написала переключение, но оно работает неправильно, подсвечивает и дочерние элементы тоже. Ну и привязано к свойству CSS, чего хотелось бы избежать.

В общем, как привязать функцию ligth, чтобы она работала вместо CSS свойства (li.selected), и как избежать подсветки дочерних элементов.

```js
for (let li of list.querySelectorAll("li")) {
  let span = document.createElement("span"); //создает пространство для клика
  span.classList.add("show");
  li.prepend(span);
  span.append(span.nextSibling);
}

list.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName != "SPAN") return;
  let childrenList = event.target.parentNode.querySelector("ul");
  if (!childrenList) return;
  childrenList.hidden = !childrenList.hidden;
  if (childrenList.hidden) {
    event.target.classList.add("hide");
    event.target.classList.remove("show");
  } else {
    event.target.classList.add("show");
    event.target.classList.remove("hide");
  }
};


//подсветка
const parentLi = list.getElementsByClassName('parent');
for (var i = 0; i < parentLi.length; i++) {
  light(parentLi[i].firstChild)
}

function light(parentLi) {
  parentLi.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    this.style.color = 'pink';
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
  })
  parentLi.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    this.style.color = 'black';
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  })
}
var liSelected;
var index = -1;
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  var len = parentLi.length - 1;
  if (event.which === 40) {
    index++;
    //down 
    if (liSelected) {
      removeClass(liSelected, 'selected');
      next = parentLi[index];

      if (typeof next !== undefined && index <= len) {
        liSelected = next;
      } else {
        index = 0;
        liSelected = parentLi[0];
      }
      addClass(liSelected, 'selected');
    } else {
      index = 0;
      liSelected = parentLi[0];
      addClass(liSelected, 'selected');
    }
  } else if (event.which === 38) {
    //up
    if (liSelected) {
      removeClass(liSelected, 'selected');
      index--;
      next = parentLi[index];
      if (typeof next !== undefined && index >= 0) {
        liSelected = next;
      } else {
        index = len;
        liSelected = parentLi[len];
      }
      addClass(liSelected, 'selected');
    } else {
      index = 0;
      liSelected = parentLi[len];
      addClass(liSelected, 'selected');
    }
  }
}, false);

function removeClass(el, className) {
  if (el.classList) {
    el.classList.remove(className);
  } else {
    el.className = el.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\b)' + className.split(' ').join('|') + '(\\b|$)', 'gi'), ' ');
  }
};

function addClass(el, className) {
  if (el.classList) {
    el.classList.add(className);
  } else {
    el.className += ' ' + className;
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.list span {
  cursor: pointer;
}

li.selected {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div>This PC
  <ul class="list" id="list">
    <li class="parent">Local Dick(C:)
      <ul>
        <li>Programm Files</li>
        <li>Users</li>
        <li>Windows</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">Local Dick(D:)
      <ul>
        <li>New Folder 1</li>
        <li>New Folder 2</li>
        <li>New Folder 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">Local Dick(E:)
      <ul>
        <li>Games
          <ul>
            <li>GTA</li>
            <li>Assasin's creed</li>
            <li>Skyrim</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Не понял про "привязку", но думаю этот код должен покрывать ваши задачи. Пишите, если нужно пояснить.

```js
const ARROW_UP_CODE = 38
const ARROW_DOWN_CODE = 40
const ENTER_KEY_CODE = 13

const disks = document.querySelectorAll('.disk')

// collapse on click

const getTargetTreeId = (disk) => disk.dataset.collapseTarget

const toggleTreeCollapse = (targetId) => {
  const collapseTarget = document.getElementById(targetId)
  collapseTarget.classList.toggle('hidden')
}

const diskClickHandler = (ev) => {
  const collapseTargetId = getTargetTreeId(ev.target)
  toggleTreeCollapse(collapseTargetId)
}

disks.forEach((el) => el.addEventListener('click', diskClickHandler))

// collapse on enter + arrow nav

let selectedDisk = null

const selectDisk = (direction) => {
  disks.forEach((el) => el.classList.remove('selected'))
  
  if (selectedDisk === null) {
    selectedDisk = 0
  } else {
    const lastDiskIdx = disks.length - 1
    
    if (direction === 'down') {
      if (selectedDisk < lastDiskIdx) {
        selectedDisk += 1
      } else {
        selectedDisk = 0
      }
    }

    if (direction === 'up') {
      if (selectedDisk > 0) {
        selectedDisk -= 1
      } else {
        selectedDisk = lastDiskIdx
      }
    }
  }

  const selectedDiskEl = disks[selectedDisk]
  selectedDiskEl.classList.add('selected')
}

const getPressedBtn = (ev) => {
  switch (ev.keyCode) {
    case ARROW_UP_CODE:
      return 'up';
    case ARROW_DOWN_CODE:
      return 'down';
    case ENTER_KEY_CODE:
      return 'enter';
    default:
      return 'invalid-btn'
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', (ev) => {
  const pressedBtn = getPressedBtn(ev)

  if (pressedBtn === 'enter') {
    const isSelected = selectedDisk !== null
    if (isSelected) {
      const collapseTreeId = disks[selectedDisk].dataset.collapseTarget
      toggleTreeCollapse(collapseTreeId)
    }
  }

  if (pressedBtn !== 'invalid-btn') {
    selectDisk(pressedBtn)
  }
}, false);
```

```css
h1, h2, h3 {
      margin: 0;
      font-weight: normal;
    }

    body {
      font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    }

    .disk {
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: background-color 0.25s, color 0.25s;
    }
    .disk:hover {
      color: pink;
      background-color: grey !important;
    }

    .disk.selected {
      background-color: aqua;
    }

    .disk-tree.hidden {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>This PC</h2>
  <ul class="list" id="list">
    <li class="disk-item">
      <h3 class="disk" data-collapse-target="disk-c">Local Dick(C:)</h3>
      <ul class="disk-tree" id="disk-c">
        <li>Programm Files</li>
        <li>Users</li>
        <li>Windows</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="disk-item">
      <h3 class="disk" data-collapse-target="disk-d">Local Dick(D:)</h3>
      <ul class="disk-tree" id="disk-d">
        <li>New Folder 1</li>
        <li>New Folder 2</li>
        <li>New Folder 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="disk-item">
      <h3 class="disk" data-collapse-target="disk-e">Local Dick(E:)</h3>
      <ul class="disk-tree" id="disk-e">
        <li>Games
          <ul>
            <li>GTA</li>
            <li>Assasin's creed</li>
            <li>Skyrim</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```